# Conditionally append to an existing concatenated string of columns

Tags: excel

MS excel :
using &(concatenating) functionality : I have appended 5 columns(B to F) to my 1st column(A), but for appending the 7th column(G) , i want to attach it only when it has some value otherwise escape from appending this 7 column in the existing appended Ist column(already has 5 columns(B to F) appended to it)

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula for A2

`=B2&C2&D2&E2&F2&IF(G2="","","NAME IS: ")&G2`

Comment: @jain007 OK, can you give me an example then? What result do you expect and how is that different from the result with my suggested formula?

Comment: sorry, you are correct , but i have a bit diff requirement : ......F2&IF(G2="","", "NAME IS: " G2).  I mean the constant has to be appended before value(G2) is NAME IS:

Comment: OK I amended my suggestion above

Comment: one more requirement: please bear with me .....F2&IF(G2="","","NAME IS: ")&G2.....the output has to be like NAME IS : "ROCKY"  ... I mean I need quotes on the value(ROCKY) I got from G2..WHAT I TRIED IS : &IF(G2="","","NAME IS: ") & """&G2"""

Comment: AND IN =B2&C2&D2&E2&F2&IF(G2="","","NAME IS: ")&G2, i get NAME IS : whether i have value in G2 or not

Comment: OK try `=B2&C2&D2&E2&F2&IF(G2="","","NAME IS: """&G2&"""")` - you need to make sure that when G2 is empty it's truly empty - not containing a space or other character.....

Comment: i tried this : this gives (when G2 is empty) :  NAME IS : "" and where there is value(like in G3) then  NAME IS : "ROCKY"..but I want to achive : nothing(G2) and  NAME IS : "ROCKY"(G3)...will ISBLANK function will help

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16381/discussion-between-barry-houdini-and-jain007)

Comment: Hey Barry , please let me if you are online and can spare 2 min for my prob soln